# LOG4J2 not logging output to a file, problems

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j2

I am using LOG4J2 in my spring project but I am unable to direct the stack trace of my app run to a file, th eoutput in th econsole is also not proper. I suspect it is unable to find the log4j2.properties file but I am clueless as to what may be going wrong here.

following are my entries in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
   </dependency>

  <dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
<version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

My log4j2.properties file which is located in src/main/resources folder where other property files are located.

This is my entry in `context.xml` file of my application

```
 <bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:config.properties</value>
            <value>classpath*:log4j2.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

this is how my `log4j2.properties` file looks like

```
name=PropertiesConfig
filters = threshold

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug
appenders = console, file

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=somesystempath..\systemLog.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
appender.file.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.file.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.file.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.file.strategy.max = 50

loggers=file
logger.file.name=com.dataextraction.processor
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE 

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

I have tried all sorts of things, adding properties file folder to classpath but it didn't work either. Deeply appreciate the input on this.

Comment: are you using spring boot?

Comment: how do I find out

Comment: You can understand via your pom.xml. What is the `parent`value in pom.xml?

Comment: No I don't think my application uses spring boot, I have     
   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>, <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>,<artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>, <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>